# How do I delete highlighted comments?

Tags: needy-streamer-overload

Usually I can delete mean stream comments by clicking the trash can icon that appears next to them. However, highlighted comments don't have a trash icon. Clicking one makes Kangel read it out at the end of the stream instead.

How do I delete highlighted comments during a stream?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighted comments cannot be deleted. They represent superchat donation messages. You can only choose whether or not to read them at the end of a stream.